# Magento 2.3.0: High MYSQL CPU Usage @ magento Cron Jobs

Tags: magento2, cronjobs

### High MYSQL CPU Usage @ Cron Jobs

Hello,

I have a problem at a server which is utilizing so much CPU so that the website is really slow.

I checked the server, logs, magento logs, and it seems its caused by the cron-jobs of magento.

I guess its related to this issue, though we have 2.3.0 here:

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11002

as stated here,

> https://www.splendid-internet.de/blog/cronjob-bug-in-magento-2-2-x-fuehrt-zu-hoher-cpu-auslastung/

---

I tried to

> select count(*) from cron_schedule;

but

> delete from cron_schedule where scheduled_at < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day);

did not change the value which was **1403** and also did not fix the server load...

---

I hope somebody has an idea whats causing this.

here are the log files, if any help

> /var/log/syslog output : pastebin.com/xsWDQNkC
>
> var/log/system.log : pastebin.com/EdfjN48t
>
> var/log/magento.cron.log : pastebin.com/0H5Y44NT

---

Edit:

I found these on Github, If this are viable Solutions - which one should be preferred?

> Magento 2 cron project to fix bugs and common cron issues.
>   github.com/magemojo/m2-ce-cron
>
> Plugin to Magento 2 which mark old cron jobs with status "running" as error. This can prevent the Magento 2 from consuming CPU
>   github.com/Alekseon/CleanRunningJobs

Comment: I recommend using some profiler (xhprof, tideways, blackfire) to find the code that makes load